# Can an unmarried woman halachically cover her hair?

Tags: halacha, women, hair

Whilst studying I came across this,

[From Sefer Kedushah, Issurei Biah Chapter 21 - Halacha 17](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960669/jewish/Chapter-Twenty-One.htm/)

> Jewish women should not walk in the marketplace with uncovered hair. [This applies to] both unmarried* and married women.

Followed by this note,

> *I.e., a widow or a divorcee. A woman who never married may wear her hair uncovered (Chelkat Mechokek 21:2).

**Simply put, may under any circumstances a never married/divorced woman cover her hair?** In the note it says "may wear her hair uncovered", which implies that such a woman could cover her hair and need never to have been married or be currently married to do so. It sounds like it is permissible.

I also wonder if it is allowed for a unmarried woman for personal tznius reasons to cover her hair.

---

When speaking of "personal tznius reasons" this discussion came up in a class. As some married women choose to, for instance, **never** uncover their hair as it is seen to be meritorious. The question was asked if it were allowed for unmarried women to have a similar, but of course situational different, high standard.

Consulting my local Orthodox rabbi is a given. However, I like hearing different perspectives. Sometimes LORs don't elaborate on their answers or answer so simply that a discussion doesn't benefit from the answer.

Comment: Perhaps related?http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/what-is-the-conceptual-definition-of-tzniut My question would be whether this specific action would yield the desired result of a higher level of modesty, when the context of the action would seem to draw more attention to an individual, not less! I would try to think of more subtle adaptations that could be made. Covering hair at a time of one's life when no one else does screams 'I'm modest, look!', which isn't what the individual is aiming for, one would assume.

Comment: In today's world dressing tzniusly already screams "Look, I am modest" as it is not the norm. One could argue this renders dressing modestly counterproductive, if everyone is going to gaze at you. Dressing tzniusly is a very small part of being tznius, which also includes behaviour, speech, and mannerism. Plenty of people abide by the dress part but not by the deeper application. 
Is it really then untznius to cover ones hair when one is unmarried? Also, what about fashion and style, may one cover ones hair with a colourful turban all the time if one finds it stylish?

Comment: That's a fairpoint, and honestly I think its beautiful that the Bnos Yisrael stand out to people by NOT flaunting themselves, be it tacitly or intentionally! I was referring more to within the Jewish community, where halacha and general practice is known. It would, with or without the dresser's intent, project a 'frumer than thou' air on to people, which would accomplish the opposite of tsnius, as outlined in the Talmud in one of the answers I linked. I'm not saying to prohibit it, certainly not in the case of style, I just don't think it will achieve the sought after high standard.

Comment: Fryda, this is a very interesting discussion, but generally comments are supposed to help to improve the posts your commenting on, so if you'd like to continue chatting, we have a room for that here: http://chat.stackexchange.com:80/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam. Thanks for your thoughts thus far!

Comment: Err, my bad, you actually need 10 more reputation to post in chat, sorry! ^ Foryour future reference, I guess.

Comment: See my answer to this *highly related* question (which is also given below): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29441/2091

Answer (score 4):

Consult your local Orthodox rabbi. The answer should end there.

But really, motivations **really** matter here. Let us say that I say that there are indeed unmarried girls in Meah Shearim who, based on this Rambam, braid their hair (so that it is not parua). And that in Yemen, Jewish unmarried girls cover their hair just like the Muslims.

If done as a deliberate divergence from the normative standards of tznius, that is, Daas Yehudis, then even if technically within the realm of **tznius** the practice is allowed, hashkafically, it might be quite problematic. There are groups of women, such as the [Burqa Babes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haredi_burqa_sect), who have formed their own sect and reject rabbinic authority. (And attract attention to themselves with their extremes of tznius, which in fact runs counter to tznius.) Halachic norms are halachic, and you should not necessarily be adding upon yourself more extreme degrees of tznius.

Could you elaborate more upon "personal tznius reasons"?

Comment: I edited the post again, to elaborate. So if your community allows it like in Yemen it is consider okay. But if the girls from Yemen move to NY they would be expected to change to conform into the prevailing community standards concerning dress. I am aware of this. However, if married women are allowed to practice the hair covering in more a more severe manner, why can't unmarried women cover their hair if they feel that this makes them closer to HaShem?

Comment: The community in Yemen **requires** it, rather than allows it. Why can't people adopt restrictive non-halachic practices according to their whims, and declare that this makes them closer to Hashem? It is the first step in rejecting Rabbinic Judaism, as defined by halachic decisors, and creating one's own religion. And this is precisely what has happened, in the present day. (For instance, to follow this thread a bit, if Rashi on the gemara explains that it is specifically hair of a married woman that is erva, why are you arguing and defining this other hair as erva, rejecting Rashi?)

Comment: also, besides for possible concerns of מחזי כיוהרא and אל תפרוש מן הציבור, think practically for a moment. You'll ruin your shidduch chances! Everyone is going to think that you are married, or divorced, or a non-virgin!

Comment: First off, I don't appreciate the phrasing of your replies and the insinuation that I am rejecting Rabbinic Judaism and that this post is about **me**. Please stop using "you" as this leads others to believe that that is my opinion or this is about myself personally, both are incorrect. Where is the _judge your fellow favourably_ notion in your comments?

Secondly, I am not rejecting Rashi as I am not defining unmarried womens hair as erva. I am merely seeking a discussion as to if it were allowed for unmarried women to have a similar, but of course situational different, high standard.

Comment: Sorry for the offense. I tend to use you in a generic way. By the way, I reject the use of "high standard". More stringent does not mean better, it just means more stringent.

Comment: First off, who says the women are actively looking for Shidduch at this current stage? Others might not see the usage of **you** as you do. And yes, stringent. 

Also, non-virgins covering their hair. Isn't that related back to that previously one could get "married" by having intercourse? If so, the non-virgin woman would be considered married.

Comment: @josh rambam clearly says a girl of about 3 years old must wear a meetpa7ath n when married a rodeedh on top. Why say it is like muslims?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob I forget. Where did the Rambam live again? ;) But yes, in the surrounding culture, the Muslim unmarried girls do similarly cover. "In Yemen unmarried girls covered their heads also, like the Muslims there; however, upon their emigration to Israel and other places, this custom has been abandoned." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzniut

Comment: yes wiki is a great source...also most of the customs teimonim had had been abandoned in israel because it is israel...

Comment: Wiki is irrelevant except for the neutral fact that this is also Muslim practice.  This isn't Muslim practice?

Comment: @joshwaxman so your saying rambam made up the law because he lived in a muslim country? so those jewish women not living in muslim countries didnt cover that way? theres no sources before him right?

Comment: @joshwaxman rabbeniu abraham ban harambam explicitly states that the muslims took the customs of the our prophets while we abandoned our ways. the muslims do a better job at being jews in many aspects than jews. in 9aneeu3th no less

Comment: @joshwaxman also christian nuns and other religious women figures dont cover their face in a similar fashion? im sure this was the norm for christian women before modernism

Comment: Of course there are sources before him, sources which were interpreted by rabbis in other lands in different ways.  The gemara refers to the ambiguous kalta, and uses the ambiguous phrase benos Yisrael.  Could cultural perception have made one interpretation more compelling or obvious than the alternative? I suspect do.  Rabbenu Avraham was referring to something he personally witnessed,  Muslims adopting Jewish practice from prior non practice? Or was he conjecturing the cause for the similarly? Amazing how kabbalah is so similar to Plato, because Plato stole it from Yirmeyahu

Comment: @joshwaxman its easy for those who stem further away from the source of halocho to pasken different than what was intended by the source. living in the middle east, women dressed differently than in some parts of europe, that doesnt mean that covering your head came from islam. https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1/542700_10150787579881063_1729260702_n.jpg this is obviously eastern european jewish women and they are covering their head with a mitpa7ath. also rabbeinu abraham ban harambam zl said specifically bout 9aneeu3th and korea3 umeeshta7awoyo and fasting

Comment: I didn't say that covering the head came from Islam. I said that the specific interpretation of kalta in the gemara, and that the gemara means to refer to a requirement for non-married women, may have been influenced by surrounding cultural practice. שיער באשה ערוה, לדעת רש"י האיסור דווקא באשת איש

Comment: also, i am very impressed with your photograph of Jews from 11th century France. I didn't know they had cameras back then...

Comment: Great discussion but again, if one were to argue that it is permitted and in what circumstance, what sources would one use?

Comment: you claimed rambam held that his idea of a covering is only of a 7eeejabi style and this is somehow because he was in a muslim area. however, the rambam talks about wigs as well in heelchoth 3bodho zoro 4 12. so would that not go against what you said?

Comment: except that isn't what I claimed. of course Rambam knows about peah nachris, which is mentioned in the gemara. (whether those are wigs, and how those are worn, is another matter.) the question is how one interprets ambiguous statements in the gemara. every person, rambam and myself included, will naturally and unconsciously gravitate (as most plausible and obvious) towards an understanding which accords with the conception of the surrounding culture. http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1404n.htm

Comment: or he holds by the fact that even though women(and men) wore wigs, it is more appropriate and the proper way of doing so as done by eemhoth as seen in the torah as well with examples in the nabee'eem?

Comment: if the gemaras are interpreted in way X, then the contestable Biblical examples can be understood as examples of local custom. after all, Mishnayot say things such as "ARABIAN WOMEN MAY GO FORTH VEILED, AND MEDIAN WOMEN MAY GO FORTH WITH THEIR CLOAKS THROWN OVER THEIR SHOULDERS. INDEED, ALL PEOPLE [MAY DO LIKEWISE]. BUT THAT THE SAGES SPOKE OF NORMAL USAGE". http://alfasi.blogspot.com/2005/07/rif-shabbat-29b.html

Comment: further, if he indeed interpreted the various gemaras as saying it was OK hair coverings (as you seem to be saying), but he omitted the halacha as established by Chazal because of what he deemed appropriate, then that would be ... a very strange thing for the Rambam to do in his halachic work.

Comment: there are things which 7azal deemed appropriate and true yet rambam deemed false and untrue, such as superstitious halochoth: 3ayeen horo3 in babo bathro

Answer (score 3):

[image: Kitzur Yalkut Yosef on women covering their hair]
This is what Yabia Omer says about women covering their hair. מעיקר הדין they don't need to until married, apart from praying or studying Torah when EVERYONE should wear a head covering. I'm not sure why so few people actually follow this.

So an unmarried woman must cover her hair during Torah/prayers according to R' Ovadia, and **can** go without at other times.

Comment: Please try to use text instead of images when citing sources.

Comment: Welcome to the Mi Yodeya! Note that the question was whether that are allowed to generally cover their hair; not whether they are allowed to uncover their hair.

Answer (score 2):

Whether an unmarried woman is "allowed" to cover her hair is not only dicussed in Halachic literature, but it is expressly discussed in the context of whether she is obligated.

The discussion, as you mentioned above in your question begins, with the the Rambam. He writes in (Issurei Biah 21:17)

> יז לֹא יְהַלְּכוּ בְּנוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל פְּרוּעֵי רֹאשׁ בַּשּׁוּק. אַחַת
>   פְּנוּיָה וְאַחַת אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ.
>
> Jewish women should not walk in the marketplace with uncovered hair.
>   [This applies to] both unmarried and married women.

The Rambam rules that even an unmarried woman is obligated to cover her hair.

The Shulchan Arukh follows the Rambam's rulings regarding both matters – that the law that a woman's hair is a sexual incitement belongs to the laws of modesty and that the law regarding head covering applies even to an unmarried woman (Even Ha-Ezer 21:1-2).

The Beit Yosef (Orach Chayyim 75) writes that the basic law is in accordance with the Rambam

However, The Beit Shemuel (Even Ha-Ezer 21, no. 5) and the Chelkhat Mekokek (there, no. 2) interpret the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch differently and distinguish between "unmarried women" and "virgins."

In other words, when the Shulchan Arukh says in Even ha-Ezer that even unmarried women are obligated to cover their hair, he is referring to unmarried women who had once been married – that is, divorcees and widows.[1](http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-18-head-covering) However, single women who have never been married are exempt from covering their hair.

The Magen Avraham (Orach Chayyim 75, no. 3) resolves the contradiction differently: The law of head covering applies only to a married woman, whereas the prohibition to walk about with "wild hair," which the Shulchan Arukh codifies in Even Ha-Ezer, relates to wild hair in its plain sense. In his view, the Sages decreed that a single woman must gather her hair together and not let it fall wild.

The accepted practice follows the Beit Shmuel and not the Magen Avraham. Thus, a single woman is not obligated to cover her hair, but a widow and a divorcee are obligated to do so ([source)](http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-18-head-covering)

For different reasons altogether, [Rav Yitzchok Berkowitz](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=yitzchak%20berkowitz&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwi135L5y5TGAhWBEywKHXblD28&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FYitzchak_Berkovits&ei=WEmAVbXTBoGnsAH2yr_4Bg&usg=AFQjCNHAUXfdFiTP3Xeslis6-WfqirIwCw&sig2=Q0cxKTIjq1xqEzSj_h3j1A&bvm=bv.96041959,d.bGg) ruled for a single woman; who was a teacher in a seminary teaching female students, that she is obligated to cover her hair.

His reasoning was that she is in a position of respect, and the underlying principle of hair covering and tznius in general (he did not provide a definitive source), is dignity and self respect, therefore she should cover her hair.

Comment: Darshinan Taama DiKra?

Comment: רגיל בפומי im just quoting. But I did hear this explicitly in a shiur from his mouth.

Comment: @DoubleAA hopefully now it is better

Comment: אִם יֵשׁ עֵדִים שֶׁיָּצָאת בְּהִנּוּמָא וְרֹאשָׁהּ פָּרוּעַ, כְּתֻבָּתָהּ מָאתָיִם.     In weding at time of Gemara, the Betula was married without kisui rosh. Nowadays, in a Charedi milieu, it may be problematic to cover the hair for a non married girl, because people can be convinced that she is married or divorced or widow Rachmana litslan

Comment: @kouty interesting, are you intending on asking according the the simple reading of rambam how you make sense  that gemara?

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv no, I say that to make something which is not the common custom may be understood wrong. If there was a minhag of Rosha parua, so they can testimony, "she was pruat rosh" and the conclusion is that she would receive 200 for her ketubba. I ask, if people say "she was already wearing a sheitel before the marriage", may be that in cas of din Torah as of the mishna, she would receive 100 only

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard anything on stopping an unmarried woman from covering her hair although if one has never been married then doing so isn't necessary. On the other hand for those that have been married and no longer are either through divorce or becoming a widow (G-d forbid for either) then we have this concept where once someone begins to take on an action they may not subtract from it. Even in the case of a single girl who has never been married if she takes on the unnecessary stringency of covering her hair then she may not stop covering her hair in the future if she decides doing so is burdensome before getting married. The other issue besides this is making it appear as if one is already married may make it difficult to get married. If people in the community see you with your hair covered already it may be assumed your married. yes that could easily be corrected by those who know you well but then there will be confusion as to why exactly you started covering your hair when it isn't necessary

Answer (score -5):

It is assur. It's a chutzpah to the rabinnic authorities! It's a statement that says "you guys didn't do your job by enforcing more rabbinical restrictions."

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if you supported the assertion that it's assur.  Thanks.  (Also, if you could reconsider the tone, that'd be great.)

Comment: This isn't at all helpful. Just like @Monica Cellio said, please provide supporting documentation for the assur statement.