# Can an engaged woman cover part of her hair as a practice in tzniut?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, hair-covering, engagement-shidduch

When a woman becomes engaged, can she practice covering her hair a little bit at a time (both in the amount of time spent with hair covered as well as how much of the hair is covered), such as wearing a knitted hat, in order to prepare for when she is married and will have to cover her hair all of the time?

Does being sephardi or ashkenazi have any impact on whether this may or may not be done?

Comment: Why should she not be able to cover her hair. Any non-married woman can wear a hat or a wig even if just for fashion or for comfort.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35959/759

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with it.

and even a single women need to cover her here when she is praying, blessing and learning tora.
(ילקוט יוסף, צא, ח - Yalkut Yossef, 91, 8)

ח נערות רווקות שהולכות בלי כיסוי ראש אף ברשות הרבים, ונוהגות להתפלל ולברך בלי כיסוי ראש, וכן מנהגן גם בבית הספר החרדי ''בית יעקב'', אף על פי שאין למחות בידן, שיש להן על מה שיסמוכו, מכל מקום לכתחלה יש להורות להן לכסות ראשן בעת שמברכות ומתפללות, ובעת שלומדות תנ''ך בהזכרת שם ה'. ולכן חובה קדושה על ראשי ומנהלי בית הספר בית יעקב ושאר בתי הספר החרדים לדבר ה', לעמוד על המשמר ולהורות לתלמידות לכסות את ראשן בעת שמברכות ומתפללות ולומדות תנ''ך. ובמיוחד יש להקפיד על כך בשעת התפלה, ודברי חכמים בנחת נשמעים, כדי שימצאו אוזן קשבת לדבריהם. וישאו ברכה מאת ה'. אך אין למחות ביד המקילות בזה, שיש להן על מה שיסמוכו. ועל כל פנים נשים נשואות שחייבות לכסות ראשן כשיוצאות לרשות הרבים, אסור להן לברך ולהתפלל בביתן בלי כיסוי הראש. וגם בשעה שקוראות בתנ''ך וכיוצא בזה, צריכות לכסות ראשן. ועליהן תבוא ברכת טוב. [שאר''י ח''ב עמו' שסח. ילקו''י סי' צא הערה ח', במהדורת תשס''ד תפלה כרך א', עמו' שיח].

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56273/759