# Eye contact with makom bris?

Tags: halacha, parts-of-the-body, see-sight-vision-blind

Is there an issur of making eye contact with your own or someone else's makom bris? I remember seeing a sign by the Arizal's mikvah in Tzfat warning strongly against it (on halachic grounds), but I couldn't find anything in Shulchan Aruch. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: See [*B'rachos* 62b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=62b&format=text), where Sha'ul is praised for conducting himself modestly in this respect (ensuring that his private areas could not be seen by others): "אמר רבי אלעזר אמר לו דוד לשאול מן התורה בן הריגה אתה שהרי רודף אתה והתורה אמרה בא להרגך השכם להרגו **אלא צניעות שהיתה בך היא חסה עליך** ומאי היא דכתיב ויבא אל גדרות הצאן על הדרך ושם מערה ויבא שאול להסך את רגליו תנא גדר לפנים מן גדר ומערה לפנים ממערה להסך אמר ר' אלעזר מלמד שסכך עצמו כסוכה".

Answer (score 4):

The Tamlud (Shabbat 118b) mentions 1 (or possibly 2) Tannaim who claimed to have never looked (הסתכל) at their "makom bris". This is presented as a rare act of extreme piety, and there is no technical law against it. The Rambam (IB 21:24) and Shulchan Arukh (EH 23:7) mention this ancient practice as well ("Some Chasidim Rishonim used to..."), seemingly as an example of how serious the pious were about avoiding bad thoughts or of how focused they were on studying Torah. It's hard for me to imagine that very many people, if any, nowadays are on the level to be attempting this.

Comment: +1. This only answers half of the question, of course. I'd assume that modesty with respect to other people would be a more appropriate practice for the average person (except in cases of a *mohel* or doctor operating on an adult, etc.).

Comment: @Fred Maybe qua politeness. I'm not sure that modesty itself plays a role (assuming of course you don't expect this to directly result in Hirhurim). Either way it's highly likely that these are the sources the OP saw referenced

Comment: Preventing *hirhurim* isn't the only factor behind modesty; there's inherent value in modest behavior (sort of per what you mentioned in [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61600/can-a-jewish-woman-sing-in-front-of-a-non-jewish-man#comment168409_61604), and related to my above comment [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/eye-contact-with-makom-bris/75992?noredirect=1#comment222767_75989)). I know a Rosh Yeshiva who conducts himself modestly when going to the mikva for this reason. And, yes, politeness is also a good reason.

Comment: +1 is it possibly related to not looking at oso makon?

Comment: @hazoriz maybe in that both are seemingly supererogatory modesty practices. they don't have the same source or anything.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe they do, both are the real ervah (when looking at it you can not say a brocho), it seems logical that a dignified person should not be looking at ervah (pudenda)

Comment: @DoubleAA is the anus erva in regard to shma (O"H 74)? Or only the genitals and feces?

Comment: @hazoriz עגבות אין בהם משום ערוה

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you very much ( https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.206.16 ), but does this include the anus itself or is it only the buttocks

Comment: @hazoriz I assume both but I have no proof

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you (I respect you opinion very much) it seems the Rav sees צוֹאָה as erva , does it not seem it's source should also be erva https://www.chabad.org/3292074/

Comment: @hazoriz there are opinions that nasal mucus is Tzoah, but no one thought that therefore the nose is Ervah

Comment: Nice, Do they say it is tzoa or that it is like tzoa?